Re-using a variable in a for loop in Cpp
I am relatively new to c++ and am implementing something in LAMMPS, and wanted to ask about if reusing a variable would cause issues (that I may not know of).. the variable in question in xi[3]
  double **angmom = atom->angmom;
  double **omega = atom->omega;
  double **torque = atom->torque;
  int *mask = atom->mask;
  int *type = atom->type;
  int nlocal = atom->nlocal;
  double *moment = atom->moment;

  double xi[3];

  if (dimension == 2) {

    for (int i = 0; i < nlocal; i++){
      if (mask[i] & groupbit) {
        xi[2] = sqdr*(random->uniform() - 0.5);

        torque[i][2] += xi[2] - eta*angmom[i][2];

      }
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < nlocal; i++){
      if (mask[i] & groupbit) {
        xi[0] = sqdr*(random->uniform() - 0.5); //One use of chi
        xi[1] = sqdr*(random->uniform() - 0.5);
        xi[2] = sqdr*(random->uniform() - 0.5);
        torque[i][0] += xi[0];
        torque[i][1] += xi[1];
        torque[i][2] += xi[2];
        xi[0] = angmom[i][1]*omega[i][2] - angmom[i][2]*omega[i][1]; //re-use chi 
        xi[1] = angmom[i][2]*omega[i][0] - angmom[i][0]*omega[i][2];
        xi[2] = angmom[i][0]*omega[i][1] - angmom[i][1]*omega[i][0];

        torque[i][0] += -eta*xi[0];
        torque[i][1] += -eta*xi[1];
        torque[i][2] += -eta*xi[2];
      }
    }
  }

As can be seen I use it temporarily for one calculation and then again for another temporary calculation in the same for loop.. is this a bad way to do this or is it OK?
Thanks!

It looks ok, but why would you do it? Why not create a separate variable? The compiler should be able to merge them if they're not used at the same time.

Reusing variables is fine. That doesn't mean it's good, that depends on the context, but it is allowed, and will work as you expect.

Thanks for your responses. I just reused it because I was lazy to declare more variables that last only one line, but I of-course can do this. I was just wondering what issues could this cause and why. A colleague told me that it may cause issues in a for loop due to 'different access patterns'

If you are lazy, you could put the double[3] in a class and overload operator+= etc. That would remove ~2/3 of the code that uses it.

The compiler will be better able to optimize the code when the variables are defined closest to where they will be used.  In this case you're not even using 2 of the 3 array elements in one of the branches, definitely a waste.

@MarkRansom okay so you mean its better to declare 'double xi;' for in the first branch,and a 'double xi[3];' in the second one...

I wouldn't even use the same name, that's extra confusing.

I've found that reusing the variable helps when debugging.  You don't have to add another variable to the watch list.  It's convenient.

One reason style guides encourage not reusing variables to much is that it reduces problems such as a variable being overwritten, and later code accessing the variable and then malfunctioning due to not getting the original [now overwritten] value.     That doesn't appear to be a concern in your code.   However, personally, I would eliminate the usage of x[i] entirely - I'll leave that as an exercise (since you'll learn a more useful lesson by doing it yourself) but, having tried it, it can simplify your code considerably (so make it easier to get right, easier to maintain).

As far as the behavior of your program is concerned: Yes, that's fine, the old values will simply be overwritten by the new ones.
But, the fact that you even have to ask this question should already give you a hint about this being a potential problem for future you, once they have to look at this code again and figure out what it does. The code is potentially difficult to understand (even more so if that function ever grows beyond its current size).
A commonly recommended best practice in C++ is to limit the lifetime of each variable to the most minimal scope you need it in. So in your case, instead of
double xi[3];

for(...)
{
  // do something with xi
}

for(...)
{
  // do something else with xi
}

you'd get a lot more clarity out of this by structuring it like this:
for(...)
{
  std::array<double,3> xi;

  // do something with xi

  // do something else with xi
}

Using std::array instead of a naked C array gives you the benefits of having a guaranteed size() function and support for standard library iterators, and setting up a new array on each loop iteration guarantees that the array is in a known state every time you start using it. Those are pieces of knowledge you gain just from that one line, without having to look at the rest of your loop body.
This design also makes your code run faster in general, since it becomes easier for the compiler to figure out what you're trying to do. This is probably not important in your case, but it's a strong argument for following this practice.
And finally, as @ted-lyngmo has pointed out, what you're doing with this array looks like vector addition (as in, mathematical vector, not std::vector); that's a good candidate for introducing a dedicated class that represents this. Maybe the library you're using already provides something like that?

Thanks for your detailed response, I have now modified my code to declare the variables closest to where they are being used. The reason I initially declared them outside the loop because i thought (i guess naively) that it may 'cost' more to create the variable each time I enter the for loop.

Yes it is indeed a similar to a vector addition (xi -> x,y,z components of a force), since I am just adding a file to an existing library, I kind-of just followed the style other files used to writing my implementation. But I will keep this in mind, thanks!

Most style guides will tell you to declare the variables as you're going to use them. It's entirely unclear why xi is an array or what it's meant to hold.
You don't have to declare variables ahead of time. You can declare them the first time you use them. For instance:
double random1 = sqdr*(random->uniform() - 0.5); //One use of chi
double random2 = sqdr*(random->uniform() - 0.5);
double random3 = sqdr*(random->uniform() - 0.5);

If you're never going to actually index the variables (your xi) with anything other than a constant, I don't understand why it's an array. But maybe there's a good reason.
Another good rule of thumb is to declare variables inside the smallest scope that makes sense.

The reason I initially declared them outside the loop because i thought (i guess naively) that it may 'cost' more to create the variable each time I enter the for loop. But I suppose this is not the case??? Xi contains x,y,z components of a force, so it seemed intuitive to me to make it an array (as with torque), but I see your point that I always index it with a constant so I could as well write xi_x,xi_y and xi_z, which might make it more readable as well.
